# Custom getter is null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

If I use this custom getter:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)queue
{
    if (_queue == nil)
    {
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:kOfflineQueueFilePath]) {
            return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:kOfflineQueueFilePath];

            //[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:kOfflineQueueFilePath];
        }else{
            return [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }
}
```

_queue is always (null). I don't know why it happens.

But if I use the same code in init:

```
  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:kOfflineQueueFilePath]) {            
        sharedQueue.queue =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:kOfflineQueueFilePath];
    }else{
        sharedQueue.queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
```

It works like magic. Why am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a custom getter, you need to set the underlying ivar before returning the value.

Change:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:kOfflineQueueFilePath]) {
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:kOfflineQueueFilePath];

    //[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:kOfflineQueueFilePath];
}else{
    return [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

To:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:kOfflineQueueFilePath]) {
    _queue = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:kOfflineQueueFilePath];

    //[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:kOfflineQueueFilePath];
}else{
    _queue =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return _queue;
```

Comment: Same goes for returning the empty array if the file doesn't exist. You need to assign a value to _queue if you're lazy loading.

Comment: Oops, yup.  I'll add that too.